# How do I save all files (or save all buffers) in Emacs?

Tags: file, emacs, save

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> saves only the current buffer.

How do I save all files (or all buffers)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Press <kbd>C-x</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, and then choose "!" for saving all buffers.

Comment: adding a C-u before that will save all buffers without prompting you

Comment: FTR, the exact command to get menu where you can press `!` to save buffers is `save-some-buffers`.

Answer (score 7):

Another way might be using [list-buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/List-Buffers.html):

1. <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-b</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> ; the third column shows '*' for modified buffers.
2. <kbd>s</kbd> ; Mark the buffer at the point to be saved.
3. <kbd>x</kbd> ; Save and/or delete marked buffers.

With [ibuffer](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode), it is slightly different:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> ibuffer <kbd>RET</kbd> ; the second column shows '*' for modified buffers.
2. <kbd>m</kbd> ; Mark the buffer at the point.
3. <kbd>S</kbd> ; Save the marked buffers.